# Sending and receiving PDF via ActiveMQ

Tags: spring, pdf, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I want to send PDFs via camel route to an ActiveMQ queue.
I need to extract these PDFs in another camel route.
Im not able to extract the data from the queue. I also tried it with  `.marshal().base64()`. The Data reaches the Message Broker but I can't extract it.

Following Error will appear:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/backoff/BackOff
>   at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.chooseMessageListenerContainerImplementation(JmsConfiguration.java:466)
>       at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.createMessageListenerContainer(JmsConfiguration.java:456).....

Does anybody has an idea?

The Object is `org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache` when using base64 marshalling.
The Object is `org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile` when just sending the pdf to the queue.

How can I extract the data to get that PDF back?

Here is the Code to deliver two different queues. But I can't extract data even of one.

```
from("file:src/main/resources/test?noop=true")
.to("jms:queue:PDF")
.marshal().base64()                 
.to("jms:queue:BASE64_PDF")
```

Comment: what is your ActiveMQ & Camel version ?

Comment: ActiveMQ.version 2.18, Camel.version 2.16

Comment: ActiveMQ.version 5.7, sorry

Comment: no problem, no more needed since your problem was resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this example works well

```
        from("file:src/main/resources/test?noop=true")
        .to("jms:queue:PDF");
        from("jms:queue:PDF")
        .to("file:src/main/resources/testReceive");
```

it is dependencies problem not Camel, verify that you have spring-core-x.x.x.jar or activemq-all-x.x.jar in the classpath

Comment: Thanks a lot!
The spring-core dependency was missing!
It works!